# Printing validation loss in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am using custom loss

```
def custom_mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return tf.math.reduce_mean(tf.square(y_true - y_pred))

model = Model(ip, op)
model.compile(optimizer=(Adam(lr=1e-4)), loss=custom_mean_squared_error)

#training
loss = model.train_on_batch(x_train,y_train)

#validating
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
val_loss = custom_mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred)

print("Val loss : %.3f"%(val_loss))
```

Error:

> TypeError: must be real number, not Tensor

How should I get the validation loss if not this way? Or is there a simple way to get real value of tensor in Keras?

Comment: you can just use model.evaluate

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy posts on SO seemed to suggest it isn't reliable so better use custom loss..

Comment: That is probably a misconception, model.evaluate will literally evaluate your loss in the data you pass in.

Comment: model.evaluate is definitely reliable! If you enable eager execution you would not have any problem printing  val_loss.

Comment: I tried model.evaluate, I am able to print the loss though it comes out to be 0 throughout. I am doing validation in batches too (due to memory issues), so is it still okay to run model.evaluate for every batch and is some kind of averaging taking place? `batch_size` should simply be size of the batch I'm feeding? @Dr.Snoopy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using model.evaluate didn't work for me, possibly I was doing something wrong. However this worked just fine:

```
K = tf.keras.backend
val_loss = K.get_value(custom_mean_squared_error(y_test, y_pred))
print("Val loss : %.3f"%(val_loss))
```